# Checkmark automatically added to rows which are not selected in tableView IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am stuck with a very weird problem. I am trying to make a small app like instagram and rightnow using Parse for backend.

What I had made till now:

- Users can sign up, logIn and follow each other
- And as user logsIn list of other users appear and user can follow/unfollow users by selecting the user name.
- When user is following checkmark appears and when user unfollows checkmark disappears

**Problem**

Problem I am facing is that when a user follows other users then other users which are not appearing in the table at the moment (which are hidden because cannot come in screen) also gets CHECKED/TICKED but not followed. Please check the screenshots I had attached for more details.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1KGz.jpg)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GPwT.jpg)

Code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

var userNames = [""];
var userIds = [""];
var isFollowing = ["" : false]
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var query = PFUser.query();

    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, errors) in

        if errors != nil{
            print("Error occurred while querying");
            print(errors)
        } else{
            userNames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true);
            userNames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true);
            isFollowing.removeAll(keepCapacity: true);
            print("User Details will come");
            for object in objects!{

                if object.objectId != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId{
                    if let userDetails = object as? PFUser{
                        userNames.append(userDetails.username!);
                        userIds.append(userDetails.objectId!);

                        var query = PFQuery(className: "followers");
                        query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!);
                        query.whereKey("following", equalTo: userDetails.objectId!);

                        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) in
                            if let objects = objects {

                                if (objects.count > 0){
                                    isFollowing[userDetails.objectId!] = true;
                                } else{
                                    isFollowing[userDetails.objectId!] = false;
                                }
                            }
                            if isFollowing.count == userNames.count {
                                self.tableView.reloadData();
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }     
    })
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
    let followedObjectID = userIds[indexPath.row]
    var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    if isFollowing[followedObjectID] == false{
        isFollowing[followedObjectID] = true;

        var  following  = PFObject(className: "followers");
        following["following"] = userIds[indexPath.row]; //This will put the objectId of the individual followed in the following field.
        following["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId; // This will put the ObjectId of current loggedIn individual in the follower field.
        following["followingName"] = userNames[indexPath.row];
        following["followerName"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username;
        following.saveInBackground();

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;
    } else{
        isFollowing[followedObjectID] = false;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None;

        var query = PFQuery(className: "followers");
        query.whereKey("following", equalTo: userIds[indexPath.row]);
        query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) in

            if let objects = objects{
                for object in objects{
                    object.deleteInBackground();
                }
            }
        })
    }

}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return userNames.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let followedObjectID = userIds[indexPath.row];
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = userNames[indexPath.row];
    if (isFollowing[followedObjectID] == true){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;
    } else{
        //print("short term lolum");
    }
    return cell
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of reusable cells, so you should remove check mark if  isFollowing[followedObjectID] == false, so just add the code to remove the check mark in else block :-

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let followedObjectID = userIds[indexPath.row];
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = userNames[indexPath.row];
        if (isFollowing[followedObjectID] == true){
          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;
        } else {
          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        }
      return cell
}
```

Comment: Done,I wanted to up vote, but don't have enough reputation right now

Answer (score 0):

Please add one key into your datasource which identify whether you have selected the row or not by setting value 0/1.

In `cellForRow` check that property's value and based on that show accessory view.

In `didSelect` make sure  that key value 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 based on row selection.